# Update the View of a web application from a DynamoDB update

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-dynamodb, vuejs2

Just wondering if anyone has done something like this. I'll add some context.

So there are two applications. A mobile app and a Vue.js web application which acts as a static DevOps board. The mobile app makes an updated to the DynamoDB table which the DevOps board should be listening too and updated the view. Like a live reload. I want to try and stay away from a timer of sorts to make a call to the DB again and pull down the objects.

I know Firebase acts like a live reload of data but I want to try and just use AWS unless someone has done something like this before.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618412/can-you-use-dynamodb-streams-to-have-realtime-triggers-like-firebase ?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't find it not matter what searches o was looking for. Might just have a Lambda update Firebase as it sounds like to much hassle for one thing. Thanks!